# "Put the way forward "

Tags: idioms

Is "Put the way forward " common in native English? I searched google book and read it from non-native writers.

For example,  "These papers put the way forward to solve it far more eloquently than I could."

Is there another alternative for it with this meaning?

Comment: I'd like to know opinions of native speakers,too.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not POINT the way forward? ( http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/point-the-way ) That's a relatively common idiom. Put the way forward is one that I've not heard of.

Comment: "map out a way forward" is the closest I have heard of.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen it put that way before but I do have some suggestions

> 1. These papers put the **method** to solve it far more eloquently than I could.
> 2. These papers put the **technique** to solve it far more eloquently than I could.

And in either example "put" may be replaced with *explain* or *describe*

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, I'm a little confused as to the exact meaning of the phrase. "The way they put it" is acceptable, as is "to put [something] forward." It sounds like that got mixed with "the way forward."

For example, they *may* mean: "The way these papers have put the solution solves the problem far more eloquently than I ever could." Or perhaps: "The solution these papers have put forth solve the problem far more..."

Answer (score 1):

> "These papers put the way forward to solve it far more eloquently than I could."

1. The sentence is badly written.
2. There is no idiom "put the way forward"
3. The idiom is however "to put [something] forward"
4. The structure is intended to be:

*These papers put X forward, far more eloquently than I could.*

X = 'the way ... to solve it'

> Is there another alternative for it with this meaning?

Here is a possible re-write:

*"These papers put forward the way to solve it - far more eloquently than I could."*